# Filters for phone and tablets in Google Play

Tags: android, filter, google-play, android-manifest, tablet

I want to put filter to my application for Google Play.
I just want to display my application to phone devices only and not to tablet users.

So what kind of filter i can put except `<screen-supports>` ?
Is there any specific filter for phone or tablet or pads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring an App is Only for Tablets;

```
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                       android:normalScreens="false"
                       android:largeScreens="true"
                       android:xlargeScreens="true"
                       android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

Declaring an App is Only for Handsets

```
<compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

For a detailed information : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHandsetApps

Edit:
No selector for xxhdpi in compatible-screens so you can use;
Tablet:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Phone :

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                     android:normalScreens="true"
                     android:largeScreens="false"
                     android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Comment: "Declaring an App is Only for Handsets"
That also filters out a lot of handsets. Galaxy S 4 etc!!

Answer (score 1):

See "[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)" article from [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com) site which which give you enough information on configuration to be done. Read "Configuration examples" for some samples.

Comment: Have already gone through those links.Want to put filter so that in android market my application won't visible while searching from tablets...!!

Comment: So does not that help you to configure your manifest file to serve your purpose ? I think it should serve. Please correct me if I have missed something

Comment: i found the problem that <compatible-screens> are introduced in API level 9 while i am developing application using API level 8.

So it will display while displaying from Tab

Comment: Oh. Then I think you should use android:maxSdkVersion in your manifest file and set it to 8. Although its not recommended by Android (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max) beyond Android 2.0.1. But marketplace still honors this tag so it should solve your purpose. However this solution will still not stop someone from installing your app on devices with Android > 2.0.1

Comment: true..
but it must have some solution to prevent from displaying in search result..
any ways thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

i've come across the same problem and i agree with what saury said earlier. you definitely need to declare a min and maxsdk and also the targetsdk. it should help weave out the handsets. one other thing you can try is to do a uses-feature telephony = true. this would weave out a few more tablets that don't have telephony feature.

also look into using compatible screens rather than supports screens. support screens is a min filter where as compatible screens is a range filter. this means that if you declare supports-screens small false, normal, true, large false, xlarge false, the market will still consider large and xlarge to be supported by the application. compatible screens will allow you declare only what your application can support. though not 100% accurate it will narrow the playing field.

also, you should look through the list of supported devices find the specs and exclude them from support manually.

EDIT: you can also get a good list of tablets off the bat by generating a sample apk and upload it to the portal. in the manifest use supports-screen small false, normal false, large true, and xlarge true. that will give you a list of tablet devices that fall under google's filter. there will obviously be odd resolution tablets but this will narrow down the list for you.